# Your browser does not support frames. I'm not using frames

Tags: html, css, frames

I'm not sure why this is happening. I'm just setting up a basic site, I've barely added anything, but Chrome seems to think i'm trying to use frames?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id='logo'><img src='img/logo-black-thin.png' /></div>
    </div><!--header-->
</body>
</html>
```

But for some reason in Chrome it creates a bunch of frameset tags and gives me this sentence in the html:

```
Your browser does not support frames. We recommend upgrading your browser.
```

I can't figure out why this is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try with <!DOCTYPE html> instead?

Comment: Where is this code going? In to a .html or .htm page? Is it possible to see your page on the Internet? I am guessing, wherever you are sticking this page in to is adding additional code.

Comment: Changing doctype causes the logo to appear but it's still adding these frameset tags into the page...

Comment: a extension on Google Chrome (using frames) can also throw this error / warning.

Comment: XHTML?  Really?  Well for starters, you don't have an opening `<html>` tag.

Comment: interesting, i'll turn off my extensions

Comment: Since you are asking a question fundamentally about the behavior of a particular browser, it would be helpful to include what version of the browser you are using.

Comment: I'm using Chrome Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: @superdj I am not sure why you think my response is not an answer and downvoting.  It is an answer, and answer for a very vague question; whatever this person is using e.g. WordPress as example is likely to be injecting the unwanted code.  There is nothing wrong in the html provided that would do so otherwise.